# How to scale fontsize on different devices programmatically (Xamarin.android)?

Tags: xamarin.android, font-size

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm actually developing an Android App. I've tried to run the app on different Android phones, but the fontSize appears either too small or large.  Programmatically, how can I scale the FontSize of texts so that it can be adjust according to the device's screen?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, make sure you are using sizes in `dp` not `px` (or `in`, `mm` etc.) as these will factor in the screen density.

If you still have an issue, look at [Screens support](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) in the Android Docs, especially *Using configuration qualifiers*.  Examples can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html).

Basically you would need to provide a different resource file for each screen size.  You should have a file something like `res/values/dimens.xml` where you store sizes for all your components.  Make sure your font sizes are declared and referenced from here.  You can then create a series of folders/files for the different screen sizes

- `res/values/dimens.xml`
- `res/values-sw320dp/dimens.xml`
- `res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml`
- `res/values-sw1024dp/dimens.xml`

where each of these folders define the ***s**mallest **w**idth* screen that that file will be used for.

Comment: Do i need to design the layouts+ contents again for each screen size?

Comment: Not if they reference the strings in the values folder(s)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is simply wrong. You have confused *density* (dpi - what those various res categories are), with *physical size*, which is the problem OP is faced with. Supplying different "density" res values will not in any way help this. Also, the only reason to use "density" bins is to have **images** be crisp at different dpis - this has nothing to do with fonts/text. (And even for that use, it is **not necessary** to supply **all** the different bins. Android will scale up/down as needed. Usually images in 2 or 3 different bins is sufficient, except for small icons.)